# Pandas add value from date

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm working with a dataset that has 'date', 'id' and 'antiquity'. For the same product the antiquity is the same all the time, even if the date changes:

```
date        id          antiquity
01/06/2015  21972.00    5241.00
02/06/2015  21972.00    5241.00
03/06/2015  21972.00    5241.00
04/06/2015  21972.00    5241.00
05/06/2015  21972.00    5241.00
```

or:

```
date        id          antiquity
01/06/2015  28794.00    4157.00
02/06/2015  28794.00    4157.00
03/06/2015  28794.00    4157.00
04/06/2015  28794.00    4157.00
05/06/2015  28794.00    4157.00
```

It is a mistake in this dataset. I need to add 1 in the 'antiquity' column for each row and id (increase the antiquity from the oldest date): the first row adds 0 to the 'antiquity' value for this id, the second row adds 1 to the 'antiquity' value for this id, the third row adds 2 to the 'antiquity' value for this product id... and so on.

I created a def that makes this operation:

```
def add_antiquity(dataframe):
    antiquity_id = dataframe.antiquity.values
    return pd.Series([int(antiquity_id[i])+i for i in range(0,len(antiquity_id))], index=dataframe.index)
```

I call this function using a single line (just to test the function):

```
new_serie = add_antiquity(df[df['id'] == 21972.0])
df[df.index.isin(new_serie.index)]['antiquity'] = new_serie
```

When I execute it, it returns to me a "SettingWithCopyWarning" but it doesn't work, the dataframe value isn't updated. I thought to do a loop for each id and call this function.

How can i do this operation? Is there any way to use any pandas function like apply() or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it work to add row number within each `id` group to `antiquity` column with `cumcount`?

```
df['antiquity'] += df.groupby('id').cumcount()
df
```

Output:

```
         date       id  antiquity
0  01/06/2015  21972.0     5241.0
1  02/06/2015  21972.0     5242.0
2  03/06/2015  21972.0     5243.0
3  04/06/2015  21972.0     5244.0
4  05/06/2015  21972.0     5245.0
5  01/06/2015  28794.0     4157.0
6  02/06/2015  28794.0     4158.0
7  03/06/2015  28794.0     4159.0
8  04/06/2015  28794.0     4160.0
9  05/06/2015  28794.0     4161.0
```

P.S. Dataset must be sorted by `date` for this to work, of course. If it's not, start with

```
df = df.sort_values('date')
```

P.P.S. If for some reason you want to do it with a function instead (which is slower, so generally not recommended), the problem with your code is that you're setting new values on a copy of the dataframe (`df[...][...]` returns a copy). The fix is to use `loc`:

```
df.loc[df.index.isin(new_serie.index), 'antiquity'] = new_serie
```